# Converting jQuery .on() Containing Selector Argument to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've been tasked with converting jQuery to vanilla JS.  I've run into trouble figuring out the proper way to convert the `selector` argument in an `.on()` event handler.

```js
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

I'm at a lost as to how the `selector` argument in `.on()` actually works and what I need to do to properly replicate it.

Here is the jQuery that I am trying to convert:

```js
// jQuery I'm converting from
$('body').on('touchstart', '#chatListDisplay .chatEl', () => { ... });
```

I've tried just including the `selector` argument the element that is used in the original jQuery by passing it into `querySelectorAll()`.

```js
// My attempt at vanilla
var chatEls = document.querySelectorAll('body #chatListDisplay .chatEl');
chatEls.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('touchstart', () => { ... });
});
```

The event handler never fires in this case, so I took some time to think of what my attempt actually represents in jQuery. It probably matches this:

```js
$('body #chatListDisplay .chatEl').on('touchstart', () => { ... });
```

As expected, changing the original jQuery to the above also results in the event handler not firing.

Comment: Is the `.chatEl` dynamically created?

Comment: Yes when the user navigates to the chat page they are loaded into the DOM. Selectors for them return Null otherwise.